# Choosing awk version on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, configuration, awk

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and making heavy use of all the great commands `awk`, `sed`, `sort` and so on.

Recently it [came to my attention](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172603/counting-the-instances-of-specific-words-in-a-text-using-awk) that Ubuntu uses `mawk` as the default implementation, but since I wanted to use some functionality specific to `gawk`, I promptly `apt-get install`ed that package.

At that point, it seems that my Ubuntu switched to `gawk` as the default, which I did not want, since it has some subtle differences in behavior (for example, `rand()` seems to be deterministic in `gawk`, which is very bad since I use it all the time).

How can I have both packages installed, but use `mawk` as the default implementation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the default via the update-alternatives mechanism, using the command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config awk
```

e.g.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config awk
There are 2 choices for the alternative awk (providing /usr/bin/awk).

  Selection    Path            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/gawk    10        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gawk    10        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/mawk    5         manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/mawk to provide /usr/bin/awk (awk) in manual mode.
```

When you want gawk instead, simply invoke it as `gawk` instead of `awk`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `update-alternatives`, I had no idea that this functionality existed.